# How can I print out everything between two empty lines from a file in Java?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader

So, I am making an application where I saved details of a client such as first name, surname, DOB, ID and address into a file called "clientListFile.txt". Everytime, a client information is added to the file there is an empty space before and after the information as shown below:

```
    //empty line
    //empty line
    fn
    sn
    1900-08-01
    1234
    addressname
    s
    8
    hn
    a
    pc
    t
    country
    //empty line
    //empty line
    fn1
    sn1
    1900-08-02 ... (etc)
```

In the code below, I am able to find if a string is stored into the file. For example, in my program, if I search "fn" or if I search "1234", it prints out which line it is located on. However, I want it to print out everything in the JTextArea called "jDisplaySearchedClientsTextArea" between the first two empty lines and the last two empty lines.

```
    private void jSearchClientsButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    
    String fn = jClientsFNTextField.getText();
    
    String clientListFile = "clientListFile.txt";

    try {
        
        BufferedReader areader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(clientListFile)));
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(clientListFile);

        //now read the file line by line...
        int lineNum = 0;
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            lineNum++;
            if (fn.equals(areader.readLine())) {

                System.out.println("ho hum, i found it on line " +lineNum);

            }
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException ioe) {
        
        System.out.println("Error while saving Head Office Address");
        
    }
  
    
}
```

Comment: You stated your requirements. Now what is your question? What stops you from implementing that functionality? You could, for example, store all lines of one entry into a list while iterating over it, reset the list whenever you pass the 2 empty lines to start a new entry and then print the list if you found a match in the entry.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The problem is that I don't know how to implement or how to write that code. I have come up with a range of ideas including your one but I don't know where to even begin.

Comment: One possibility would be to read the entire input file into a List of Client instances, where the Client class contains all the information about a client, use the List to show clients in your GUI, and write the entire List out when the application ends.

Comment: `However, I want it to print out everything in the JTextArea called "jDisplaySearchedClientsTextArea" between the first two empty lines and the last two empty lines.` You state the logic of what you want to do. Now you need to implement that logic in code. You need to test for an empty line, then when the line is not empty print out your information, then if there is another empty line, exit the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a method something like this:

```
/**
 * Parses and searches a "clientListFile.txt" data file based on the supplied 
 * search criteria.<br>
 * 
 * @param dataFilePath (String) The full path and file name of the data file 
 * to search in.<br>
 * 
 * @param searchCriteria (String) What to search for in each data record 
 * contained within the supplied data file.<br>
 * 
 * @param useContains (Optional - Boolean - Default is True) This optional 
 * parameter by default is boolean '<b>true</b>'. This means that every search 
 * done in any data file record is carried out by locating the search criteria 
 * (ignoring letter case) within any record field value location that <u><b>contains</b></u> 
 * the search criteria. An example 
 * of this would be:<pre>
 * 
 *      Search Criteria:  "fred"
 * 
 *      A Data Record:
 *      =============
 *      First Name: Danny           (No Match)
 *      Surname:    Fredrikson      (Match - Fred......)
 *      Birthdate:  1957-11-07      (No Match)
 *      Cient ID:   1234            (No Match)
 *      Address:    3233 Sandy St.  (No Match)
 *      City:       Fredericton     (Match - Fred.......)
 *      Province:   New Brunswick   (No Match)
 *      etc.....</pre><br>
 * 
 * If boolean '<b>false</b>' is optionally supplied then the search is done 
 * based on <u><b>equality</b></u>. This means that every search done in any data file 
 * record is carried out by locating the search criteria within any record 
 * field value that is <b>equal to</b> (ignoring letter case) the supplied 
 * search criteria. An example of this would be:<pre>
 * 
 *      Search Criteria:  "fred"
 * 
 *      A Data Record:
 *      =============
 *      First Name: Fred            (Match - Fred)
 *      Surname:    Fredrikson      (No Match)
 *      Birthdate:  1957-11-07      (No Match)
 *      Cient ID:   1234            (No Match)
 *      Address:    3233 Sandy St.  (No Match)
 *      City:       Fredericton     (No Match)
 *      Province:   New Brunswick   (No Match)
 *      etc.....</pre><br>
 * 
 * @return  A List Interface Object of Type String - {@code List<String>}.
 */
public static List<String> searchInRecords(String dataFilePath, String searchCriteria, boolean... useContains) {
    boolean UseCONTAINSinSearches = true;
    if (useContains.length > 0) {
        UseCONTAINSinSearches = useContains[0];
    }
    int fileLinesCounter = 0;
    int fieldsCounter = 0;
    int dataRecordsCounter = 0;
    int criterialFoundRecords = 0;
    boolean inRecord = false;

    List<String> foundRecords = new ArrayList<>();

    String[] fields = new String[12];

    // 'Try With Resources' use here to auto-close the reader.
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dataFilePath))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            fileLinesCounter++;
            line = line.trim();
            if (line.isEmpty() && fieldsCounter == 0) {
                inRecord = true;
            }
            else if (inRecord && fieldsCounter <= 11) {
                fields[fieldsCounter] = line;
                if (fieldsCounter == 11) {
                    String record = new StringBuilder("").append(fields[0]).append(", ")
                            .append(fields[1]).append(", ").append(fields[2]).append(", ")
                            .append(fields[3]).append(", ").append(fields[4]).append(", ")
                            .append(fields[5]).append(", ").append(fields[6]).append(", ")
                            .append(fields[7]).append(", ").append(fields[8]).append(", ")
                            .append(fields[9]).append(", ").append(fields[10]).append(", ")
                            .append(fields[11]).toString();
                    dataRecordsCounter++;
                    // Search Type 1 (using CONTAINS where criteria is anywhere in a field)
                    if (UseCONTAINSinSearches) {
                        for (String field : fields) {
                            if (field == null) { continue; }
                            if (field.toLowerCase().contains(searchCriteria)) {
                                if (!foundRecords.contains(record)) {
                                    foundRecords.add(record);
                                    criterialFoundRecords++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // Search Type 2 (using exact match to field but ignoring letter case)
                    else {
                        for (String field : fields) {
                            if (field == null) { continue; }
                            if (field.equalsIgnoreCase(searchCriteria)) {
                                if (!foundRecords.contains(record)) {
                                    foundRecords.add(record);
                                    criterialFoundRecords++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                fieldsCounter++;
            }
            else {
                fieldsCounter = 0;
                inRecord = false;
            }
        }
    }
    // Handle the exceptions (if any) any way you see fit.
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
    
    /* The following integer type variables can be used to supply related
       class member variables. They serve no specific purpose within this
       method and can be removed if desired. Sometimes this information can 
       be handy.       */
    System.out.println("Overall Number of Data File Lines: --> " + fileLinesCounter);
    System.out.println("Overall Number of Records in File: --> " + dataRecordsCounter);
    System.out.println("Criterial Search  - Records Found: --> " + criterialFoundRecords);
    
    return foundRecords;
}
```

Far better of course to utilize a database for this sort of thing and the use of a **Client** class. Even with a file type data storage method (like you are using), you would really want a Client class to keep that data organized and store the data more like in a CSV style (**C**omma **S**eparated **V**alues) file. Here is an example of a ***custom*** CSV data file:

```
Client ID,  First Name,  Sir Name,  Date Of Birth,  Address,                 City,          State/Province,    Postal Code,   Country,      E-Mail,                      Phone Number
=======================================================================================================================================================================================
1234,       Fred,        Flinstone, 1957-11-07,     2977 Oriole Cooky Way,   Bedrock,       Stones Throw,      V2Q5W8,        Canada,       his-email@yahoo.com,         604-776-1121      
1235,       Wilma,       Flinstone, 1964-11-30,     2977 Oriole Cooky Way,   Bedrock,       Stones Throw,      V2Q5W8,        Canada,       her-email@yahoo.com,         604-776-3466      
1236,       Jack,        Naso,      1993-03-18,     33912 CrackShack Ave,    Vancouver,     British Columbia,  V2Z1D2,        Canada,       myemailaddy@hotmail.com,     856-302-1122      
1237,       William,     Shakaconn, 1996-12-13,     1212 Playwrite Street,   Langely,       British Columbia,  V2T4C9,        Canada,       playme@gmail.ca,             777-664-9351
```

In this custom CSV file the data is laid out more like a table and records are more legible even when just reading the file itself. If you want your Client class to do this sort of thing then just E-Mail me.